# MySQL | Update records insert of insert if field exists

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have a table with three fields:

- Auto increment integer (primary key)
- String which should be unique
- integer containing a value which is not unique

See picture here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRRqC.png)

The value for the integer field does not need to be unique.

**My problem:**
I pull data from an API and insert the string and third field (integer) into the table. At the moment i am truncating the table and inserting again to avoid duplicates. How do I do it so if the string is existing, it just updates the third field (integer), if it does not exist it will insert the row as normal.

I am aware of the ON DUPLICATE KEY technique however my 'key' is the primary key and it is the string field that i want to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string field should be unique, then declare it as unique:

```
alter table add constraint unq_table_string unique (string);
```

Then, `on duplicate key` will find a match when this constraint is also violated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query -

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `your_table`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`hash_name` );
```

This will add unique index to your table and remove all duplicate hash_name and will make sure that no duplicate hash_name being inserted in future.